# Share Eclipse Android projects with SVN

Tags: android, eclipse, svn

I'm using Eclipse for Android development in two different environments (MacOS and Win7). Under MacOS I checked all relevant projects into SVN except specific folders (/bin, /gen) and files (.classpath, .DS_Store, .properties). But somehow the projects do have several failures in Win7 then. What am I doing wrong?

Failures are for example: /bin folder problems and write-access to .classpath. And some projects have a reference to a OpenCV project which is not part of SVN but rather manually added to Eclipse in both environments.

Is there a step-by-step How-To somewhere? Help appreciated.

Comment: You should copy/paste one (or more) error messages verbatim, "/bin folder problems" is a very fuzzy description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Check in all files** (including hidden files or folders), except for /bin or /gen. Your Eclipse projects are otherwise incomplete and may use different settings on the 2 machines (e.g. one machine compiling with Java 5 compatibility, one with Java 6 compatibility). At least JDT, ADT and other important plugins all avoid storing machine specific properties or absolute paths there, so you can transfer the settings without issues.

Comment: I switched to Git instead of SVN an there I checked in everything except for bin/ and gen/ some postings say that hidden files and project related files should be excluded as well, but then I had problems on the other machine because Eclipse ADT did not realize them as projects. But you have to make sure that all relative path are correct. Meaning that projects that are referenced but not in Git, should have the same relative location in both machines or should be checked in as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could be hitting an issue of line endings, path separators (\ vs /) and such.

I would look into using git. Git doesn't mark all files are RO by default so you can have an editor change files without that issue.

Also look into Android Studio. Gradle uses convention over configuration so the files should be somewhere independent of directory/path separators (/ vs ) which, if eclipse or some other plugin, is expection bin/bar which will work on Mac/Linux but windows would be bin\bar.